# use formula -1/n to all column in R

Tags: r

how can i use formula -1/n to all 100 column if column meets condition less then or equal to 0.66.

```
>read.table("~/Desktop/foldchange.csv",sep = ",",header = T)-> e
>e$X<-NULL
X85 = c(0.6858110076, 
0.6763217948, 0.6777037797, 0.2477567046, 0.150890861, 1.4494420148
), X86 = c(0.6344889595, 0.3238520432, 0.6821503806, 1.2469503345, 
0.1967564907, 0.9990678878), X87 = c(0.3741192137, 0.6666912747, 
1.3112335946, 0.3164985959, 0.2201466863, 0.4888482588), X88 = 

c(0.3119556762, 
0.2054043658, 0.5943294282, 1.0861248907, 0.5118729002, 1.6492037186
), X89 = c(1.027412097, 0.0790170448, 1.3589022881, 0.4327791809, 
1.4486313814, 0.3194611987), X90 = c(0.894763906, 0.4914006772, 
1.1347816469, 0.6430273491, 0.3178809648, 1.073061393), X91 = c(0.628493603, 
0.4914143019, 1.0304501567, 0.7207211083, 0.1074300226, 0.3380868057
), X92 = c(1.3026422866, 1.0840773898, 1.3157557712, 0.4775421572, 
0.8786902151, 0.5843273081), X93 = c(0.3481263605, 0.4261844178, 
1.3500611203, 1.7260437158, 0.2817451212, 0.5406176877), X94 = c(0.7430725423, 
0.8863342393, 1.378542478, 1.390921504, 0.7538782912, 0.8613948595
), X95 = c(0.2210888181, 0.3678770932, 0.2777278428, 0.4768601083, 
1.1094668285, 0.9609648852), X96 = c(0.2547985487, 0.3360082943, 
1.8998726579, 0.8861691474, 0.1442648297, 1.060979381), X97 = c(0.1777107507, 
0.8203439062, 1.3921490902, 0.1545204838, 0.2105020128, 1.1803859218
), X98 = c(0.6985609805, 1.1660525045, 0.9002045257, 0.9645039183, 
0.3830624545, 0.7138528496), X99 = c(0.5112135444, 0.1983123941, 
0.4952269467, 0.7465842632, 0.6262820927, 1.2293865608), X100 = c(1.2151302507, 
0.2111249156, 0.9733885591, 0.2127452763, 0.2148471781, 0.3619375307
), X101 = c(0.4816703304, 1.0963122409, 0.9959054752, 1.3647606965, 
0.4948024448, 1.0318667062), X102 = c(0.6428557554, 0.2657349241, 
1.6929046554, 0.3760316507, 0.4520281529, 0.2360539647)), .Names =    c("Names", 
"X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", 
"X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", 
"X20", "X21", "X22", "X23", "X24", "X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", 
"X29", "X30", "X31", "X32", "X33", "X34", "X35", "X36", "X37", 
"X38", "X39", "X40", "X41", "X42", "X43", "X44", "X45", "X46", 
"X47", "X48", "X49", "X50", "X51", "X52", "X53", "X54", "X55", 
"X56", "X57", "X58", "X59", "X60", "X61", "X62", "X63", "X64", 
"X65", "X66", "X67", "X68", "X69", "X70", "X71", "X72", "X73", 
"X74", "X75", "X76", "X77", "X78", "X79", "X80", "X81", "X82", 
"X83", "X84", "X85", "X86", "X87", "X88", "X89", "X90", "X91", 
"X92", "X93", "X94", "X95", "X96", "X97", "X98", "X99", "X100", 
"X101", "X102"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to apply -1/n  for all values (< 0.66) in column X0 to X5 where n will be the value which will satisfy the condition < 0.66

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... then **edit your question**!

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data (or a definition of the dataframe), e.g. `dput(head(e))`

Comment: Don't write `dput()` in your question without actually putting the `dput()` output. If you had put the `dput` output, it would start with `structure(list(...` and it would be copy/pasteable into our R sessions, which is really nice. You, apparently, just did `head(e)`.

Comment: Hi @Gregor I am editing the post but i am not sure whether again it will be correct or wrong

Comment: No, it should start with `structure(list(...`. And since you have so many columns, just do a subset, say the first 6 columns and first 6 rows: `dput(e[1:6, 1:6])` is plenty. Now that your question is answered, just keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: Sure @Gregor !!

Answer (score 0):

For a single column:

```
df %>% mutate(Col = ifelse(Col =< 0.66, -1/Value, Value))
```

so for your dataframe (df) check the Column (Col) that would be the name of the column and then use the formula if true or leave it as it is if false.

```
mutate_at(e, vars(X0:X5), function(x) ifelse(x < .66, -1 / x, x))
```

Comment: l1 <- c(1007,1.0175053,1.0156994,0.8783851,0.9457506,0.8922344,1.0268757)
l2 <- c(1008,0.8697151,0.8788073,1.0911145,0.9658687,0.7904880,0.9769305)
l3 <- c(1009,1.0175053,1.0156994,0.8783851,0.9457506,0.64,0.63)

df <- data.frame(l1,l2,l3)    
df
df %>% mutate(l3 = ifelse(l1 < 0.66, -1/l1, l1))

Comment: it's always helpfull to create an example data frame. So all answers use the data u provide, I created one and for the values smaler 0.66 the value is ajusted. hope it hepls you

Comment: This will apply on one column only

Comment: Hi @Gregor its not changing any value below 0.66 to -1/n.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor for putting it together.